# What happens if we put a pinch of salt on the ice cubes which is melting in the water?

Tags: experimental-physics, water

What happens if we put a pinch of salt on the ice cubes which is melting in the water?

How will the ice react to the salt, and what other things will happen after mixing them?

Comment: There are ice cubes in water on which i add a pinch of salt...so this addition of salt on cubes leads to what type of reaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt lowers the melting point of water - so when you put salt on ice floating in water it will "dissolve" - locally the ions of Na+ and Cl- will mix in with the water molecules and cause tiny puddles of salty water on top of the ice cube.

The salt will weigh down the ice cubes very slightly so they will "sit" a tiny bit lower in the water. Note that the process of salt dissolving in water is endothermic so it keeps the ice a tiny bit colder.

If the salt water from the dissolution of the salt reaches the main body of the water, the density of that water will be slightly (very slightly) higher; this makes the ice cubes (if they have not melted yet) sit a bit higher on the water.

Not sure of any of this was what you were looking for...